# How to insert a file path into a MySQL table using php?

Tags: php, mysql, file, path, insert

I'm trying to insert a file path into an empty MySQL table with PHP 5 but slashes and other characters are removed so I can not use to the string when calling it from the table. What function do I use to preserve the file path without losing characters?

```
$rawpath    = "F:\Business\test.htm";
$url        = "Business";

$query      = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `sites` (`url`,`base`)".
              "VALUES ('$rawpath','$url');";
echo $query;
```

Outputs:  INSERT IGNORE INTO `sites` (`url`,`base`) VALUES ('F:\Business\test.htm','Business');

```
$query      = "SELECT * FROM `sites` WHERE `base`='Business';";
$row        = mysql_query($query);
$url        = mysql_result($row,0,"url");

echo $url;
```

Outputs: F:Businesstest.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with backslashes `\`, which are used often to escape certain characters. You need to escape this backslashes (with another backslash), to make them appear. So, if you use double quotes, write `\\` instead of just `\`, or use `addslashes($url)`.

I'm not quite sure that you need to escape them if you use just single quotes.

Comment: Perfect! addslashes($url) was a great suggestion. Thank you Carlos.

Comment: @Carlos Campderros Yes, He needs to escape even he use single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your back slashes. Try this

```
$rawpath    = "F:\\Business\\test.htm";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do: `quotemeta($rawpath)` before the insert statement. All the backslashes will be correctly escaped after that.